# Removing a "," from the end of the strings in an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string array that has `"lastname,"` in the first cell. I want to remove the `" , "`

I don't want help with the rest, just how to pull the comas out of the last names.

This is the input given

```
1 T T T T T F T T F F
Bobb, Bill 123456789  T T T T T F T T F F
Lou, Mary  974387643  F T T T T F T T F F
Bobb, Sam  213458679  F T F T f t 6 T F f
Bobb, Joe  315274986  t t t t t f t t f f
ZZZZ
```

This is the output wanted
    Results for quiz 1:

```
123-45-6789  Bill Bobb 10
974-38-7643  Mary  Lou 9
213-45-8679  Sam  Bobb 5
315-27-4986  Joe  Bobb 10

The average score is 8.5
```

This is what I have

```
while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz")) //while the input is not "zzzz" loop will run
  {
    String [] key = input.split ("\\s+"); //takes String input and converts it to an array seperated by " "
    input = br.readLine ();
      while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz"))
      {
        String [] student = input.split ("\\s+");//takes in student information seperated by " "
        String lname = student[0].substring(0);
        String id = student[2].substring(0,3) + "-" + student[2].substring(3,5)+"-"+ student[2].substring(5);//inserts "-" into id#
        System.out.println (id);
        System.out.println (lname.trim("\,"));
        input = br.readLine ();
      }
  }
```

Comment: `String.replaceAll(",","")` or simply `String.substring(0,String.length()-1)`

Comment: @kaetzacoatl Use `String.replace()` unless you need regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz"))
          {
            String [] student = input.split ("\s+");//takes in student information seperated by " "
            String lname = student[0].substring(0,student[0].length()-1); //removes "," from last name.
            String fname = student[1];
            String id = student[2].substring(0,3)+"-"+student[2].substring(3,5)+"-"+student[2].substring(5);//inserts "-" into id#

```
        int score =0;
        int i =1;
        while(i<=key.length-1)
          {
            if(key[i].equalsIgnoreCase(student[i+2]))
            {
              score++;
              i++;
            }
            else
              i++;

          tscore += score;
          scount++;
          }
        if(scount == 0)
            System.out.println ("Empty class data");

        System.out.println(scount);
        System.out.println ("Results for quiz " + key[0] + ":" +'\n');    
        System.out.println (id + " " +fname+ " "+lname+" "+score);
        System.out.println(key[1] +":"+student[3]);
        input = br.readLine ();
      }
```